# select records between two date in vb.net gives error operand type clash

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

i need to select some records from table Tr_cashbook between two date. the date field is newdt in which i need to compare data and the records should be shown in crystal report named rptCash2. the newdt field has datetime property. here is the code on the command button

```
    bdcon.Open()

    Dim QueryString As String
                QueryString = "Select * from Tr_Cashbook where (Cast(newdt as date)>=  " & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & ") and (Cast(newdt as date) <= " & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & ")"

    Dim Adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(QueryString, bdcon)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Adapter.Fill(ds, "Tr_Cashbook")

    rptCash2.Load()
    rptCash2.SetDataSource(ds)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptCash2

  bdcon.Close()
```

but this is not working
when i press the command button it gives error as operand type clash: date is incompatible with int. i am not able to find out where i go wrong . help me with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parameters` instead of hard-coded sql string.

Your parameterized query shoud be:

```
 QueryString = "Select * from Tr_Cashbook where newdt>=@date1 and 
     newdt<= @date2"

 Dim Cmd as new SqlCommand(QueryString,bdcon)
 Cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1",SqlDbType.Date).Value=DateTimePicker1.Value
 Cmd.Parameters.Add("@date2",SqlDbType.Date).Value=DateTimePicker2.Value

 Dim Adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
 Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
 Adapter.Fill(ds, "Tr_Cashbook")
```

You may use BETWEEN AND syntax:

```
QueryString = "Select * from Tr_Cashbook where newdate BETWEEN  @date1 AND @date2"
```

Comment: still not working. shows the same error. operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: @user1059908 - What is the field data type of newdate?

Comment: now it gives error  "Must declare the scalar variable "@date1"

Comment: @user1059908 - Please follow the code I've pasted. If you can edit your post then add current/working code in it.